# How to make text field as a picker in react native?

Tags: react-native, text, picker

I want a textview with name DAY and when i click on the text the piker shows up..and that have 1 to 31 values.. and selected values are set to textview

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#fff', marginHorizontal: 5, fontSize: 14 }}>
                        <Picker selectedValue={this.state.user} onValueChange={this.updateUser}>
                            <Picker.Item label="Steve" value="steve" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Ellen" value="ellen" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Maria" value="maria" />
                        </Picker>
                    </View>
```

Comment: have you tried using a placeholder text for DAY?

Comment: no @kenmistry do you have any sample code so please give me